# Passing pointers to member function as returned values to QObject::connect()

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

For design reasons, I need to come up with a way to call `QObject::connect()` where the function pointers are passed in as returned values of function calls. Namely, instead of using the vanilla syntax`connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, receiver, &Receiver::updateValue);`, I have to do something like the following:

```
//in main.cpp
SENDER *sender = new SENDER;
RECEIVER *receiver = new RECEIVER;
connect(sender, sender->get_func(), receiver, receiver->get_func() );
```

where SENDER and RECEIVER are defined as follows:

```
#include <QObject>

class SENDER : public QObject {

  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void(* get_func() ) (double, double);

  signals:
    void send_data(double x, double y);

};


void (* SENDER::get_func() )(double, double)
{
    return send_data;
}


class RECEIVER : public QObject {

  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void receive_data(double x, double y);
    void(* get_func() ) (double, double);

};

void (* RECEIVER::get_func() )(double, double)
{
    return receive_data;
}


int main()
{
    SENDER *sender = new SENDER;
    RECEIVER *receiver = new RECEIVER;
    QObject::connect(sender, sender->get_func(), receiver, receiver->get_func() );
}
```

Attempts to compile give me the following error:

```
/home/abc/work/mainwindow.cpp:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘MainWindow::connect(SENDER*&, void (*)(double, double), RECEIVER*&, void (*)(double, double))’
     connect(sender, sender->get_func(), receiver, receiver->get_func() );
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of converting your code to a [mcve] so we can all reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions aren't returning member-function pointers.  Here's how `SENDER` should be written:

```
class SENDER : public QObject {

  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void (SENDER::*get_func())(double, double);

  signals:
    void send_data(double x, double y);

};


void (SENDER::*SENDER::get_func())(double, double)
{
    return &SENDER::send_data;
}
```

`get_func()` needs to be declared as returning a pointer to member function taking `(double, double)` and returning `void`.  And the implementation needs to qualify the name of the member being returned, and use the address-of operator, `&`.

Similar changes must be made to `RECEIVER`:

```
class RECEIVER : public QObject {

  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void receive_data(double x, double y);
    void (RECEIVER::*get_func())(double, double);
};

void (RECEIVER::*RECEIVER::get_func())(double, double)
{
    return &RECEIVER::receive_data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `get_func`s aren't returning pointer-to-member functions, which is what connect is expecting. They are returning pointer-to-functions.

The *bodies* of them are also going to fail to compile, as you return a member function (with incorrect syntax).

You should instead declare them as

```
//sender.h
#include <QWidget>

class SENDER : public QWidget{

  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void (SENDER::*get_func)(double, double)();

  signals:
    void send_data(double x, double y);

};

//sig_sender.cpp
#include "sender.h"

void (SENDER::*)(double, double) SENDER::get_func()
{
    return &SENDER::send_data;
}

//sig_receiver.h
#include <QWidget>

class RECEIVER : public QWidget{

  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void receive_data(double x, double y);
    void (RECEIVER::*get_func)(double, double)();

};

//sig_receiver.cpp
#include "receiver.h"

void (RECEIVER::*)(double, double) RECEIVER::get_func()
{
    return &RECEIVER::receive_data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `auto` to deduce the type (C++14) and return `&Class::method`:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

class SENDER : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    auto get_func(){
        return &SENDER::send_data;
    }
signals:
    void send_data(double x, double y);
};

class RECEIVER : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void receive_data(double x, double y){
        qDebug()<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << x <<y;
        QCoreApplication::quit();
    }
    auto get_func(){
        return &RECEIVER::receive_data;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    SENDER *sender = new SENDER;
    RECEIVER *receiver = new RECEIVER;
    QObject::connect(sender, sender->get_func(), receiver, receiver->get_func());
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, sender, [sender](){
        emit sender->send_data(1.0, 2.0);
    });
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Or:

```
class SENDER : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void (SENDER::*get_func())(double, double){
        return &SENDER::send_data;
    }
signals:
    void send_data(double x, double y);
};

class RECEIVER : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void receive_data(double x, double y){
        qDebug()<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << x <<y;
        QCoreApplication::quit();
    }
    void (RECEIVER::*get_func())(double, double){
        return &RECEIVER::receive_data;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `using` or `typedef` to define type for a pointer to member function:

```
class SENDER : public QWidget{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    typedef void (SENDER::*PtrFunc)(double,double); // PtrFunc pointer to member function
    PtrFunc get_func () { return &SENDER::send_data; }
  signals:
    void send_data(double x, double y) {}
};


class RECEIVER : public QWidget{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    using PtrFunc = void (RECEIVER::*)(double,double);
    void receive_data(double x, double y) {}
    PtrFunc get_func() { return &RECEIVER::receive_data; }
};

SENDER* sender;
RECEIVER* receiver;
//..
QObject::connect (sender, sender->get_func(), receiver, receiver->get_func());
```

by using typedef it is easy to put it as result type.